ROracle installation errors on EL8
I am trying to install ROracle package version 1.3-1.1 on R version 4.4.1. The OS is RHEL 8.9, kernel 4.18.0-513.24.1.el8_9.x86_64. I've installed Oracle client 23 including JDBC, ODBC and all development rpms (from https://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL8/oracle/instantclient23/x86_64/index.html), and I use OCI_INC and OCI_LIB environment variables to specify locations of inc files and libraries for OCI. When running R CMD INSTALL ROracle_1.3-1.1.tar.gz I'm getting the following error:
* installing to library ‘/export/apps/prod/*****/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/4.4’
* installing *source* package ‘ROracle’ ...
** package ‘ROracle’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating src/Makevars
** libs
using C compiler: ‘gcc (GCC) 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-20)’
gcc -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG -I/usr/include/oracle/23/client64  -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection  -c rodbi.c -o rodbi.o
rodbi.c: In function ‘rociDrvInit’:
rodbi.c:532:31: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
     RODBI_ERROR((const char *)errMsg);                                 \
                               ^~~~~~
rodbi.c:217:15: note: in definition of macro ‘RODBI_ERROR’
         error(err)
               ^~~
rodbi.c:1221:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘RODBI_CHECK_DRV’
   RODBI_CHECK_DRV(drv, __FUNCTION__, 1, TRUE,
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
rodbi.c: In function ‘rociConInit’:
rodbi.c:552:31: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
     RODBI_ERROR((const char *)errMsg);                                 \
                               ^~~~~~

(and a few more screens of similar looking messages). I also experimented with an earlier (19.23) version of the client with the same result. Can someone please help me understand what I might be doing wrong? Thanks!
Best regards,
Nikolai

I have the same problem in Ubuntu 22.04

ROracle 1.4-1 downloaded from Oracle site in a tar.gz file did install correctly for anyone else having the issue.

You're not doing anything wrong, just being restrictive about compilation warnings. The package's code quality should be improved to avoid such errors, but that's on Oracle.
The -Werror=format-security flag is set for gcc (you can see it on the line that starts with gcc), and some things on the package's code trigger that warning, and the compilation fails.  You need to find out where that flag is being set (e.g. CFLAGS= in ~/.R/Makevars).  Once you find out where it is set, try removing it, reinstall the package (and set it back on afterwards, if you want to).

Thanks, that was helpful. Turns out the flag was set in multiple places in R's Makeconf file (in my case, it was located in /usr/lib64/R/etc/Makeconf), and was indeed responsible for the compilation errors.

Don't know if you did, but you shouldn't change /usr/lib64/.../Makeconf, since that's R's default. The proper way here is to create your own ~/.R/Makevars and set CFLAGS there to override the default. Again, this is Oracle's fault, by shipping packages that don't compile under R's default configuration. Hopefully they'll update it.

Is there a flag to cancel the effect of -Werror=format-security? I think that changing ~/.R/Makevars is fine when you want to add flags but I don't know how remove flags this way.

You can't remove it AFAICT, but you can reset the whole thing, minus that flag. So if you have CFLAGS=-a -b -c -Werror=format-security -d -e as R's default, you'd set CFLAGS=-a -b -c -d -e on ~/.R/Makevars.
